# In Linux, does any instance of java.io.Console represent the controlling terminal of the current JVM process?

Tags: java, linux, io, console

In Linux, a process may or may not have [a controlling terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface#Controlling_terminals_and_process_groups). In Linux, does **any instance** of `java.io.Console` class **always** represent the controlling terminal of the current JVM process?

I guess yes, because the following from  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html describes something similar to the controlling terminal of a JVM process:

> Methods to access the character-based console device, if any,
>   associated with the current Java virtual machine. Whether a virtual
>   machine has a console is dependent upon the underlying platform and
>   also upon the manner in which the virtual machine is invoked. If the
>   virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without
>   redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console
>   will exist and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display
>   from which the virtual machine was launched. If the virtual machine is
>   started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then
>   it will typically not have a console.

Comment: The system console can be fetched through System.console() if it is available. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#console() Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I think it is important to clarify the concept of controlling terminal of a process, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface#Controlling_terminals_and_process_groups

Comment: What do you need it for?